# 'Task status' box in ReactJS - unable to find suitable design component

Tags: reactjs, layout, material-ui, antd, react-component

I've spent quite a substantial amount of time trying to find out what one would call this type of component (example from Google Drive) that displays the status of running jobs/tasks (or whatever else). I am a non-native English speaker so I can't formulate exactly what one would call this thing.

[image]

I have tried searching for the following types of components, but with no luck yet: 'dialog box, permanent modal, progress popup, status updater, running task component, task modal, status modal' etc., but I haven't been able to pin down anything useful yet.

I have also looked through Material UI and Ant Design, and haven't been able to find exactly what one would call this type of component (which might make my life easier).

Comment: In Material-UI, Snackbar (https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/#snackbar) would be the best starting point for this.

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Modal](https://ant.design/components/modal/), [Toast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toast-notifications), or [Snackbar](https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/) are all what you'd call this as a starting point, but then some of the customisation will be up to you - for example you might have to define two divs, one black and one white, and containing the data you want to contain. It's unlikely that there will be an exact match for what you're looking for.